# How can make a group of similar skills in PYTHON

Tags: python, parsing, nlp

I have multiple similar skills in the resume and after parsing getting similar skills like
`angular, angularjs, angular 6, angular js, angular 7` etc.

My question is how can make a group of similar skills so that can keep it like a group of similar skills. Thanks

Comment: can you define *similiar*?

Comment: That is a non-trivial problem and depends on your definition. Do you already have all the skills pre-extracted and now just want to group/cluster them? Or do you want to dynamically extract these skills while determining which group they might belong to?

Comment: I have pre-extracted skills and now just want to group/cluster them

Comment: You could start with some simple rule-based approach such as comparing strings while ignoring numbers, spaces and "-" characters. Like `to_remove = str.maketrans('', '', '0123456789- ')` and then compare them using `if s1.translate(to_remove) == s2.translate(to_remove): ...`.

Comment: What other skills are there, apart from `'angular'`? How many different skills do you have total, and how many different groups do you expect to end up with?

Comment: As it is already visible in your example things might be more complicated for a lot of cases so you could try to hand-craft some advanced rules like combining the mentioned ones with a Levenshtein-distance (https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.edit_distance.html) or using pre-defined lists of tags (e.g. check out the "synonyms" and "related tags" lists in SO tag info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info). Also you could look into acronym detection but that is usually a complicated task to do automated.

Comment: are Java and Javascript similar in your definition of similar?

Comment: Thanks! everyone for replying to me. @SembeiNorimaki in my definition of similar skills is  ``angular, angularjs, angular6,angular7`` these are similar ``reactjs, react6`` and ``microsoft, microsoft office, office, ``    and ``corel, corel draw,draw`` and ``human resource, human resource management, resource management`` these are the example which i can provide you. I think you can understand now my problem. Thanks

Comment: yes I understand that you group skills that share the same words. that's why I ask you what will happen if you put java and javascript. will it group them as similar? Also grouping Microsoft and Microsoft Office as similar is questionable.

Comment: java & javascript are different skill. These are all  will put in a different group

Comment: I want to remove the duplication of one skill from the array. Thanks

Comment: We can keet it like a similar group of one skill

Comment: this task may need NLU and AI.